# SQL query to find the most recent timestamp for several ID's

Tags: sql, join, max, inner-join

I'm trying to run a query that returns the last 'game' or action that a certain group of users performed. I've had to join several tables to finally get what I want, but this basically returns each users games now. I'd like to just take their last game. I added max(___) to timestamp in the query but it ended up just returning the most recent game played and that is it. Ideally I'd like to see each user and their last action.

```
SELECT teamName, test_teams.userID, test_teams.timestamp AS signup, sponsorship, test_results.timestamp, stadium, win+draw+lose AS games 
    FROM test_teams 
INNER JOIN test_profile
    ON test_teams.userID = test_profile.userID
INNER JOIN test_results
    ON test_teams.userID = test_results.homeTeamId
WHERE test_teams.timestamp >= '2015-11-04 00:00:00' and win+draw+lose > 100
ORDER BY games desc;
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following SQL statement gives you the latest timestamp/action per team:

```
SELECT MAX(timestamp) as latestTimestamp, homeTeamId
  FROM test_results
  GROUP BY homeTeamId
```

It can be joined with the other 2 tables

```
SELECT teamName, tt.userID, tt.timestamp AS signup, sponsorship, tr.latestTimestamp, stadium, win+draw+lose AS games 
FROM test_teams tt
INNER JOIN test_profile
  ON test_teams.userID = test_profile.userID
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT MAX(timestamp) as latestTimestamp, homeTeamId
  FROM test_results
  GROUP BY homeTeamId) tr 
  ON test_teams.userID = tr.homeTeamId
```

Comment: Thanks! One question  - on line 2 it says "FROM test_teams tt" - bit confused here! as well as second to last line where it says "GROUP BY homeTeamId) tr" - I assume you've abbreviated the tr for test_results and the tt for test_teams?

Comment: Yes, correct. It's a standard SQL features http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp

Comment: Thanks again man! not saying much, but certainly the coolest query I've writ...well, attempted to write, gotten help with, and successfully executed!